# Array of Empty Objects vs Array of Objects - Firebase and Polymer

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, polymer, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to use the Polymer Shop template to create an online store, replacing the standard category objects with objects from Firebase Cloud Firestore. After initializing the database, I'm trying to use the objects to show a list of categories in a drawer menu.

This top example is with Cloud Firestore. As well as the code, you can see via screenshot what the console prints out when categoryList is console logged.

[Cloud Firestore Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U18TT.png)

```
let categoryList = []
firebase.firestore().enablePersistence()
      .then(function() {
          // Initialize Cloud Firestore through firebase
      var db = firebase.firestore();

      db.collection("product-categories").where('active', '==', true)
        .get()
        .then(function(querySnapshot) {
            querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                    // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
            categoryList.push(doc.data())
            });
          })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
          });  
      });
```

Here's the code in the original Polymer Shop template, as well as a screenshot showing the output when categoryList is printed to the console.

[Polymer Shop Template Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBVZ5.png)

```
(function() {
let categoryList = [
  {
    name: 'oils_and_tinctures',
    title: 'Oils and Tinctures'
  },
  {
    name: 'concentrates',
    title: 'Concentrates'
  },
  {
    name: 'Vape',
    title: 'Vape'
  },
  {
    name: 'topicals',
    title: 'Topicals'
  },
  {
    name: 'pet_products',
    title: 'Pet Products'
  }
];
```

It seems like I need an array of empty of objects and then to fill those objects. How do I get the data from Firebase Cloudstore to match the format of the original template data?

Thanks in advance for anyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

```
querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) => {
    categoryList.push({ name: doc.name, title: doc.title }) 
}).
```

OR

```
function CategoryData(name, title) {
    this.title = title;
    this.name = name;
}

querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) => {
    categoryList.push(new CategoryData(doc.name, doc.title)) 
})
```

Using the second way you can define what ever structure you like.

Comment: Thanks for the help! This definitely made it easier to extract certain Firebase properties, but apparently Polymer uses a system of paths, not objects to represent data. Overall it also has something more to do with the fact that Polymer doesn't use dirty checking and allow you to push data to arrays and then bind those to DOM elements. I dunno. I'm still trying to figure it out. Thanks for te help though!

Comment: When you push data to an array, array ref doesn't change. That is why polymer does not notify. If you want observe bindings, observe `array.splices`. This will notify changes.